# either the cd command isn't working the way it should, or my understanding of it is flawed

Tags: shell-script

So, I am using a windows emulated bash shell, as installing Linux via VM takes too long and results in a very slow customer that I'm NOT going to deal with. So, for now I'm using Windows' bash shell.

So, I type the command pwd which gives me the path /home/shibuya.

so, I want to mess with the cd~/home/shibuya path, but when I type that it says "no such file or directory."

I also tried cd../shibuya.

again, no such file or directory.

I tried cd~shibuya no such file or directory.

Comment: There’s a space between cd and the pathname, right? Typing ‘cd~/shibuya’ is not the same as ‘cd ~/shibuya’.

Comment: Also ‘~’ is a shortcut for your home path, so if your username is abc, then ‘cd ~/def’ is a shortcut for ‘cd /home/abc/def’.

Comment: If I type cd ~/home/shibuya, it does the WEIRDEST thing. . . It prints home/shibuya/home/shibuya: No such file or directory. Like whaaa? Microsoft, your bash shell is tearing me apart.

Comment: @MarkU That solved the problem , thanks MarkU.

Comment: @Goro I can also type cd ~/shibuya or cd../shibuya and it works! Yush!

Answer (score 2):

Commands in shell scripts consists of one or more *words*, in the vast majority of cases separated by [space characters](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS). The shell (for example Bash) then [*splits* those words](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) into tokens which it interprets to figure out what the command should do. (This is different from many other languages, where *strings*, rather than words, have to be quoted, and where parameters to functions, rather than commands, have to be enclosed in parentheses.) In the case of `cd` you can run it in many ways, including at least

- `cd` on its own (that is, type `cd` on a line on its own and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to go back to the home directory,
- `cd -` (<kbd>cd</kbd>, then <kbd>Space</kbd>, then a hyphen, <kbd>-</kbd>) to go to the previous directory you were in within the same shell, or
- `cd some/path` to go to that path *relative* to the current directory.

Now, `~` will [*expand*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.22.2BAH4.22) to your home directory, so `~/home/shibuya` will expand to `/home/shibuya/home/shibuya` if `/home/shibuya` is your home directory. So you probably wanted either `cd ~` or (as above) just `cd`.